# How can we find the space $x : x^\top T x = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given symmetric matrix $T$ with real entries, is there a way to find the space of all $x$ such that $$x^\top T x =0$$?

This is superficially similar to the null space of $T$, so I hope methods similar to those for finding the null space may exist.  I have explored that avenue without good results so far.  My only thought, unresolved so far, is that this is the space of vectors related to the zero eigenvalue.

Is there a name for this property that $x$ must have relative to $T$, for $x^\top T x=0$?

Comment: Your question has little to do with Algebraic Geometry

Comment: If $T$ is symmetric, then $Q(\mathbf v)=\mathbf v^TT\mathbf v$ is a quadratic form, so you’re essentially asking about a specific level set of this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matrix $T$, we have eigenvectors $v_i$ and corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_i$.

Theorem: given vector $\bf a$ such that $$\sum_i a_i^2 \lambda_i = 0,$$ all $x:=\sum_i a_i v_i$ satisify $x^\top T x = 0$.

Proof: Since $v_i$ are eigenvectors of $T$, and since $T$ is symmetric with real entries the eigenvectors are orthonormal,
$$ x^\top T x 
= \left(\sum_i a_i v_i \right)^\top T \left(\sum_i a_i v_i\right) 
= \left(\sum_i a_i v_i \right)^\top \left(\sum_i a_i v_i \lambda_i \right)
= \sum_i a_i^2 \langle v_i, v_i \rangle \lambda_i
= \sum_i a_i^2 \lambda_i = 0.
$$
Q.E.D.

Since $\bf a$ can be constructed from the null space of $\bf \lambda$ by restricting it to the quadrant of nonnegative values, we can also construct $x$ this way.

Comment: This is indeed the correct characterization. Note that your proof already delivers an if-and-only-if statement: The vectors $x$ such that $x^TTx=0$ are precisely the vectors you identified.

Answer (score 3):

Denote $Z:=\{x: \ x^TTx=0\}$.

This set is *not* equal to the set of eigenvectors to the zero eigenvalue.
Consider $T=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$, then
$$
x^TTx=0
$$
if and only if $|x_1|=|x_2|$. This is fulfilled for, e.g., $x=\pmatrix{1\\1}$, which is *not* an eigenvector of $T$.

The set of such vectors $x$ is also not a vector space. One can only prove
that $Z$ is closed with respect to scalar multiplication
$$
x\in Z\Rightarrow \lambda x\in Z\ \forall \lambda.
$$
Closedness with respect to addition of vectors does not hold in general.

The set $Z$ is trivial ($=\{0\}$) if and only if $T$ is positive definite or negative definite. If $T$ has positive and negative eigenvalues, then $Z$ is non-trivial ($\ne\{0\}$)by the mean-value theorem.

Comment: $x\in Z\Rightarrow \lambda x\in Z$ makes sense for a quadratic form. Can we characterize the non-trivial solution sets as a collection of lines through the origin?

Comment: Yes. These are kind of infinite cones.

Comment: Do you mean "$Z$ is non-trivial if and only if $T$ is neither positive definite nor negative definite"?  I don't follow the logic of that paragraph as written.  (Or alternately $Z$ is trivial if and only if $T$ is positive definite or negative definite?)

Comment: Is your statement "one can only prove..." intended to imply no other proof about the set is possible?  I think that statement would require some proof!

Comment: see edit........ thanks for the note